# Variational Auto Encoder (VAE) sampling from prior vs posterior

Tags: neural-networks, variational-bayes

I have been reading the original VAE paper,[Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114). In VAE, when generating samples, why do we sample from prior instead of the learned variational posterior(Fig 5 in the paper)? Similarly when visualizing learned data manifold why do we take inverse CDF of prior(multivariate unit Gaussian) instead of variational posterior(Fig 4)?

Comment: True. But every implementation online seems to suggest to sample from the standard normal including the paper for generating novel images. The reparamaterization trick is actually used only while training / testing reconstructions. So those learned mean and log var are not used to sample new images if I'm not wrong.

Comment: sampling the posterior on the latent space would provide multiple reconstructions of a single input, and not reconstructions of a diverse region of the image space

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I understood about VAEs:

- the posterior refers to p(z|x), which is approximated by a learnt q(z|x), where z is the latent variable and x is the input.
- the prior refers to p(z). Often, p(z) is approximated with a learnt q(z) or simply N(0, 1).

The posterior explains how likely the latent variable is given the input, while the prior simply represents how the latent variables are distributed without any conditioning (in CVAEs conditions are added here as well).

Hence, in training, we want to learn a good posterior approximation (Evidence) that explains the input, but in testing we want to generate random samples following the prior distribution (unless you want to condition them some how).